# Frequent update one filed of django model

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

Imagine, I have `News` models with many text fields

```
class News(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    lead = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
    content = models.TextField()
    ...
    last_visited = models.DateTimeField()
```

Every time my `News` object outputs, I update `last_visited` field:

```
news.last_visited = datetime.datetime.now()
news.save()
```

This code makes Django override all model fields:

```
UPDATE news SET title='...', subtitle='...', last_visited = '...' WHERE id = '...';
```

Instead of just one:

```
UPDATE news SET last_visited = '...' WHERE id = '...';
```

I worried how bad it is and is it worth of thinking about.

Django documentation offers queryset update but it looks not very elegant:

```
def upd(obj, **kwargs):
    obj.__class__._default_manager.filter(pk=obj.pk).update(**kwargs)

upd(news, last_visited=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I use mysql backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using update but with a cleaner approach:

```
class News(models.Model):

    def update_visited(self):
        News.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(
                        last_visited=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using queryset `update` is good. It removes the possibility that you overwrite changes to other fields by accident.

I know you're worried that it looks inelegant, but you only have to use it once in your `upd` function, then use `upd` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to use this on more than one model (guessing this because you pass `obj` to your `upd` function) it would probably make sense to have some base class that implements the `last_visited` field and your `News` class inherits from this class... Then you could do the update just on your base class.... Another possibilty would be putting the `last_visited` information into a seperate model and referencing the `News` model either through a `ForeignKey` or a `GenericForeignKey` (in the case you want to keep a 'history' for different models).